# Why widget is not showing in widget area

Tags: php, wordpress

Why widget is not showing in widget area ?

here is the code:

php

```
<?php

/*
Plugin Name: Weather Widget
Plugin URI: https://your-website.com/
Description: A weather widget for displaying current weather conditions in a chosen city.
Version: 1.0
Author: Your Name
Author URI: https://your-website.com/
*/

function weather_widget() {
  ?>
  <div id="weather-widget">
    <h2>Vremenska prognoza</h2>
    <input type="text" id="city-input" placeholder="Upiši grad">
    <button id="get-weather-btn">Dohvati vremensku prognozu</button>
    <div id="weather-data"></div>
  </div>
  <?php
}

function add_weather_widget() {
  wp_enqueue_script('weather-widget-script', plugins_url('weather-widget.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'));
  wp_enqueue_style('weather-widget-style', plugins_url('weather-widget.css', __FILE__));
  add_shortcode('weather_widget', 'weather_widget');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_weather_widget');
```

js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  const API_KEY = 'your_api_key'; // zamijenite sa svojim API ključem
  const API_URL = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=';
  const API_UNITS = 'metric';
  const widget = $('#weather-widget');
  const cityInput = $('#city-input');
  const weatherData = $('#weather-data');
  const getWeatherBtn = $('#get-weather-btn');

  getWeatherBtn.on('click', function() {
    const city = cityInput.val();
    if (!city) {
      alert('Upiši naziv grada!');
      return;
    }
    const apiUrl = `${API_URL}${city}&appid=${API_KEY}&units=${API_UNITS}`;
    $.getJSON(apiUrl, function(data) {
      const weather = data.weather[0];
      const temperature = data.main.temp;
      const description = weather.description;
      weatherData.html(`<p>Trenutno vrijeme u ${city}: ${temperature} °C, ${description}</p>`);
    })
    .fail(function() {
      alert('Dogodila se greška prilikom dohvaćanja vremenskih podataka!');
    });
  });
});
```

css

```
#weather-widget {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

#city-input {
  padding: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 250px;
}

#get-weather-btn {
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #0073aa;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#weather-data {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

plugin normally installs in Wordpress, without errors

but on widget list there is no widget

I have also tried othere theme, but problem is here

I know that i need to input API, but i hope this is not a problem ?

I hope you can help me

Thank you

Comment: _"Why widget is not showing in widget area ?"_ - Because you did not actually implement a widget - but a shortcode.

Answer (score 1):

First problem is that you cannot define `add_shortcode` inside `wp_enqueue_scripts`.

Second, inside the shortcode function you cannot put `echo` but `return`.

```
function weather_widget($attr=[], $content='') {
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <div id="weather-widget">
        <h2>Vremenska prognoza</h2>
        <input type="text" id="city-input" placeholder="Upiši grad">
        <button id="get-weather-btn">Dohvati vremensku prognozu</button>
        <div id="weather-data"></div>
    </div>
    <?php
    
    return ob_get_clean();
}

add_shortcode('weather_widget', 'weather_widget');

function add_weather_widget() {
    wp_enqueue_script('weather-widget-script', plugins_url('weather-widget.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'));
    wp_enqueue_style('weather-widget-style', plugins_url('weather-widget.css', __FILE__));
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_weather_widget');
```

It would be advisable to read the documentation carefully because there are examples of how to handle this function.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_shortcode/

It is very important to go through the documentation to understand the functionality.

And I suggest that `add_shortcode` you put it inside the `init` action so that WordPress can deliver all the data adequately.